# How to make a button delete a row in my database that's also in my HTML?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some codes which pretty much gives me all of the Emails and Times from my database and puts it in my HTML. For every Email there is 1 Time. I pretty much want a delete button next to all of the Email+Time and when the button is pressed I want it to delete just that Email+Time. This is my code which gives me all the Emails + Times from my database:

```
    require_once"database.php";
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reserveringen");

if($result->num_rows != 0) {

    $message = array();
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Email = $rows["Email"];
        $Tijd = $rows["Tijd"];
        $message[] = "$Email $Tijd <input type='button' value='Verwijder afspraak' name='verwijderen'/>";
        }

    }




    <?php

        if($message) {
            foreach($message as $value) {
                ?>
                <p><?= $value; ?></p>
            <?php
            }
        }

        ?>
```

I've tried some stuff and I do have a delete button next to every Email+Time, but how do I get it that when it's pressed to just delete the Email+Time that's next to it.
http://prntscr.com/5x08bl

EDIT:
Okay, let me try to be a bit more specific.
In my database I have a table called "reserveringen". In that table there are 2 columns called "Email" and "Tijd" Everytime when I add an Email and Tijd it automatically places a button next to it in my HTML.(See printscreen above). In this printscreen you can also see that there are 3 Emails + Tijds at the moment and they all have their own button next to it. I'm not a PHP-expert but I want that if I click on 1 of those buttons it deletes the Email + Tijd that's next to it. Not just in my HTML, but also in my database. I hope this is a bit more specific.

Comment: Max from Skillcapped?

Answer (score 0):

Surround your button with `<a>` tag and in href pass path to your controller and id that u want to delete

```
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Email = $rows["Email"];
        $Tijd = $rows["Tijd"];
        $message[] = "$Email $Tijd <a href='delete?id=$Tijd'><input type='button' value='Verwijder afspraak' name='verwijderen'/></a>";
        }

    }
```

and then, in scirpt under `delete`, get the id that you passed via `$_GET['id']` and remove it from database and then redirect to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Your possible solution is to add an anchor tag on the button and post the id of the respective content along with it.
The anchor href has the value of the page that performs the deletion query of depending upon the received content id.

```
<a href = "delete.php?id='$id'"><input type='button' value='Verwijder afspraak' name='verwijderen'/></a>
```

where delete.php executes your deletion query according to the id(email id) you pass along with it.

On deletion page simply get this id with `$_GET['id']` and perform the deletion query on the table.
After deleting redirect the page using `header('Location:yourpage.php')`

Comment: I wont suggest him a `$_GET` instead better to use `$_POST` you don't want users to play that URL especially in delete feature

Comment: It would be actually sending data(id), so it logical to use `$_GET` to get that id and do necessary function.

Comment: Okay, correct me if I'm wrong. You want me to make a delete.php page, Then place a query in that page which deletes the Email in my database. If I understand correctly then I'm still bumping against a problem. My Email doesn't have an Id. The Email is on my website because the Email+Tijd is in my $message. The Email itself doesn't have an Id on the page with the delete button.

Comment: I will suggest you to add an extra column of `id` with `auto_increment, not null, primary key`. This `id` will come in handy for any operation that you want to perform with the content. And there is no need for you to display this id, keep it for operational purpose.

Comment: But if I want to get that id from my database I'm gonna have to make another query right?(Sorry, not the best in PHP)

Comment: Yup, u'll have to add a new column in your database. :)

Comment: The basic idea is to add a column that helps you distinctly identify your each and every content from one another. So...I would recommend, you as a good practice to add a `Primary key` to your table, so that any operation could be done easily.